# Why is the collection of all groups a proper class rather than a set?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28set_theory%29),

> The collection of all algebraic objects of a given type will usually
> be a proper class. Examples include the class of all groups, the class
> of all vector spaces, and many others. In category theory, a category
> whose collection of objects forms a proper class (or whose collection
> of morphisms forms a proper class) is called a large category.

I am aware of Russell's Paradox, which explains why not everything is a set, but how can we show the collection of all groups is a proper class?

Comment: take the free group on each set

Comment: It's too dang big!

Comment: When you say "class" you want to say "proper class." Sets are also classes.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The collection of singletons is not a set. Therefore the collection of all trivial groups is not a set.

If you wish to consider "up to isomorphism", note that for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$ you can consider the free group, or free abelian group with $\kappa$ generators. These are distinct (up to isomorphism, that is), and since the collection of cardinals is not a set the collection of groups cannot be a set either.

Comment: In more categorical language, the first paragraph shows that $\text{Grp}$ is not a small category, and the second paragraph shows that $\text{Grp}$ is not even an essentially small category (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+category).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I suppose that they show that $\mathrm{Ab}$ is also neither small nor essentially small. Right?

Comment: Yes, and lots of variations. Much more generally, a theorem of Freyd asserts that if a small category has all small colimits, then it is a poset.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how that'd apply to the other types as a well. If anyone else is reading this: [Cantor's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_paradox) proves that the collection of cardinals isn't a set