# Is TOP a small category?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, foundations

A quick question... is the category of topological spaces and continuous maps a small category? If so how do we know and if not how do we know not?

Comment: given that any set has the discrete/indiscrete topology, it seems unlikely that you'll have a set of objects

Comment: Related: [Is there a set of all topological spaces?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746084/is-there-a-set-of-all-topological-spaces/)

Answer (score 18):

Since each set may be viewed as a topological space (e.g. via the discrete topology) there are "at least" as many topological spaces as sets; so no, **Top** is not small.

It is, however, *locally* small: for $X, Y$ fixed spaces, the collection $Hom(X, Y)$ of all continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$ is a set (note that there are at most $\vert Y\vert^{\vert X\vert}$-many of these).

Answer (score 16):

Categories of sets with structure are basically never small — even something as simple as the collection of one-element sets is not small. (there are too many choices for what that single element can be!)

Some such categories can be *essentially small*, meaning that they are equivalent to a small category. For example, the category of finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ is not small, but it is essentially small.

However, **Top** is not even essentially small, for another simple set-theoretic reason: for every cardinal number, there is a discrete set of that cardinality, and these are all non-isomorphic. The collection of cardinal numbers is not small, and consequently the collection of objects of **Top** cannot be small.

Or put differently, **Set** itself is a full subcategory of **Top**, with one such embedding given by selecting the discrete topology (the indiscrete topology works too). Since **Set** isn't small, neither is **Top**.